titleps package: How to make boxed page number and header line appear as one element?
I'm trying to refine a document design I've pieced together from various TeX.SE answers. I'm using titleps for page styles and headers, with the page number in a colored box. I've adapted code from @skillmon 's answer for wrapping the page number in a box, and @gonzalo-medina 's answer for chapter styling.
My current issue is with the header. The page number box and the head rule appear as separate elements, but I want them to look like one unified component.
Here's what I have now: (a colored box with page number floating above a separate horizontal rule)

And here's what I'm aiming for: (a colored box with page number seamlessly connected to the horizontal rule)

This is the relevant part of my code:
\newpagestyle{main}{
  \sethead[\WrapNumberInBox{page}][][\chaptertitle] % even
  {\chaptertitle}{}{\WrapNumberInBox{page}} % odd
  \renewcommand\makeheadrule{\color{MidnightBlue}\rule[-1\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{.3ex}}
  \setfoot{}{}{} 
}

How can I tweak this to make the boxed page number and head rule look like one cohesive element?
Here's a MWE [a maximal working example :)] that reproduces the issue:
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[explicit, newparttoc]{titlesec}
\usepackage[rightlabels, dotinlabels]{titletoc}
\usepackage{titleps}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=2.432cm, right=2.432cm, top=2.9cm, bottom=3.3cm, headheight=.5cm, footskip=1.25cm}

\usepackage{iftex}
\ifluatex
    \usepackage{lua-ul}
\else
    \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\fi

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%    Helper commands for styling section titles
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newbox\TitleUnderlineBox%
\newcommand*\TitleUnderline[2][MidnightBlue]%
  {%
    \begingroup%
    \color{#1}\setbox\TitleUnderlineBox\hbox{\colorbox{#1}\strut}%
    \ifluatex%
      \underLine[height=.3ex, top=.3ex-\dimexpr\dp\TitleUnderlineBox\relax]{#2}%
    \else%
      \renewcommand{\ULthickness}{.3ex}%
      \setlength{\ULdepth}{\dimexpr\dp\TitleUnderlineBox\relax}%
      \uline{#2}%
    \fi%
    \endgroup%
  }%
\newcommand*\WrapNumberInBox[2][MidnightBlue]%
{%
  \colorbox{#1}%
    {%
      \makebox[2.5em][c]%
        {%
          \color{white}%
          \strut%
          \csname the#2\endcsname%
        }%
    }%
    \ifstrequal{#2}{page} % This condition removes the underline connecting the box to the underlined text when the box contains a page number, so only the box is shown.
    {}
    {\kern-.1em\TitleUnderline[#1]{\kern.1em\ \ \kern.1em}\kern-.1em}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                 titleps settings
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpagestyle{main}{
  \sethead[\WrapNumberInBox{page}][][\chaptertitle] % even
  {\chaptertitle}{}{\WrapNumberInBox{page}} % odd
  % \setheadrule{.4pt} % set width of the rule below the headline
  % \headrule
  \renewcommand\makeheadrule{\color{MidnightBlue}\rule[-1\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{.3ex}}
  \setfoot{}{}{} % odd/even (If no optional arguments are given the odd-page settings applies to both even and odd pages)
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                 titlesec settings
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Chapters formatting
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
  {\startcontents\normalfont\huge\bfseries\color{MidnightBlue}}%
  {
    \pagestyle{empty}\filleft\hspace*{-60pt}%
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{
      \normalfont\bfseries\large\color{MidnightBlue}\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}
    }%
    \hspace{10pt}%
    {
      \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
      \colorbox{MidnightBlue}{
        \parbox[c][3cm][c]{2.5cm}{
          \centering\color{white}\fontsize{80}{90}\selectfont\thechapter
        }
      }
    }%
  }%
  {20pt}%
  {\filcenter\titlerule[2.5pt]\vskip4pt\Huge#1}%
  [
    {
      \vspace*{2pc}%
      \normalsize%
      \startcontents%
      \printcontents{l}{1}[1]{}\vspace*{2pc}%
    }
  ]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Sections formatting
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]%
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}%
  {\WrapNumberInBox{section}}%
  {0pt}%
  {\MakeTitlecase{\TitleUnderline{#1}}}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\pagestyle{main}

\chapter{Chapter title}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Section title}
\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Subection title}
\lipsum[3-20]

\end{document}

Any ideas on how to achieve this integrated look would be greatly appreciated!

Personally, I sould just use \AddToHook{shipout/background} and a tikzpicture. (see tikzpagenodes).

tbh, I've never given TikZ a shot because it seems pretty intimidating to me. @JohnKormylo

You can change the vertical shift of the rule to, e.g., \rule[-1.5ex]. I can't figure out the exact dimensions of the colored box, but I guess you know how much padding there is around the content, and with that number, you can change -1.5ex to a more flexible solution.

Haha, I'm a bit embarrassed I didn't see that. It was right in front of me the whole time. Thanks for the help.
